# heidisql - create database with uppercase Camel Case Format

Tags: heidisql

i create table with Tbl-ProductModifierGroup but on HeidiSQL it will display tbl-productmodifiergroup, how to slove this problem? Can i create table with CamelCase Format? which is Tbl-ProductModifierGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the server variable `lower_case_table_names` to the value of 0 in your my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=0
```

But be aware of side effects mentioned on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HeidiSQL. Could you tell us what kind of DBMS you're running where you would like your table to be created? And please post a snippet of your `CREATE` code.

A sidenode before using camel case: keep in mind to check your DBMS for case sensitivity differences on platforms.